# User is not getting added to Monitored Users in debug logs

Tags: debugging

I am simply adding user in 'Monitored Users' in Debug Logs. But User is not getting added.

Comment: confirmed from my side that i am facing same issue as well !Anybody from salesforce who can comment on this please ?

Comment: Is this happening in a specific sandbox/PRD instance/ all the instances? what instance are you guys on?

Comment: This is happening to me in cs13 and none of the workarounds have workeds, has anyone opened a case with Salesforce?

Comment: I am facing the same issue ..no luck with the suggested answers yet.

Answer (score 8):

After deleting all the Previous Logs we were able to add log to the user .Use Delete All Button in the logs and keep clearing the logs until you have erased all the logs .Hope this helps

I got the trick finally.Although this is the bug but here is work around .

Open the developer console from set up and keep it open in browser .Also now if you do a transaction and go to monitor>debug_logs ,You will see your log there .

[image]

Update:

Official work around from sfdc and root cause of issue explained below

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0DsAAK

Comment: I have deleted all the Previous Logs. But still not able to add User. I can add other users but not my user.

Comment: Even for me it was happening from yesterday .I deleted previous logs and then was able to add to it .Lets hope you get that soon .

Comment: I also have deleted all the previous logs and still cannot add my user Id. Wondering if there is an issue where my user Id was already being monitored before the Winter '14 upgrade, since all the other users I seem to be able to add a monitor to without issue.

Comment: @DeborahOrth Updated my answer .Please see

Comment: Sometimes even clearing the log dont help much !One way to do is open the developer console and also open the Monitoring>Debug Logs .Once log is generated in developer console also you will see in debug logs . –

Comment: I am also facing the same issue and i deleted all the previoud logs but still not working

Comment: open the developer console and repeat the transaction.you will see log in both developer console also monitoring>debug logs

Answer (score 8):

Since none of the suggested solutions have worked for me. I am posting here what it seems to be the official workaround provided by Salesforce.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T0DsAAK

**Workaround**

This issue is caused by a problem with the expiration date in the related TraceFlag object, that is available via the Tooling API.

To be able to monitor debug logs for the affected users, you may follow these steps:

1) Login into Workbench (https://workbench.developerforce.com/), 
2) Go to /restExplorer.php 
3) Select GET and enter in the below query for ALL TraceFlags

/services/data/v29.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT%20Id%20FROM%20TraceFlag

You can also narrow the query for just the user you want by adding a WHERE clause.

4) Copy the IDs and delete them by selecting DELETE and entering the following URL on all the IDs you want to delete.

/services/data/v29.0/tooling/sobjects/TraceFlag/{Trace_Flag_ID}

Comment: You can also narrow the query for just the user you want by adding a WHERE clause.

4) Copy the IDs and delete them by selecting DELETE and entering the following URL on all the IDs you want to delete.

/services/data/v29.0/tooling/sobjects/TraceFlag/   ..... ..        can some one help me in above two steps..

Comment: I tried on the CS11 sandbox instance but its not working.. When I try to DELETE, I am getting the 'Methods Not Allowed error', HTTP Method 'DELETE' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET. i tried this with the a user who has System Admin profile. Without the logs its really difficult to debug the code..

Comment: The query to narrow down to the user: /services/data/v29.0/tooling/query/?q=SELECT%20Id%20FROM%20TraceFlag where TracedEntityId = ‘userId’

Answer (score 0):

Go to Developer console --> Debug --> Clear --> Log panel this should clear all logs and then trying adding the user in Debug logs. It should work.

Comment: Sometimes even clearing the log dont help much !One way to do is open the developer console and also open the Monitoring>Debug Logs .Once log is generated in developer console also you will see in debug logs .