# Debug problem in Winter 14?

Tags: apex, visualforce, debugging

My SF sandbox environment was upgraded to Winter 14 release a few days ago.  I've been doing VisualForce and Apex development for the past few days without any problems but then today, I ran into an odd - but quite debilitating - problem.

I go to the Debug Logs page and attempt to add a user to monitor.  I select the desired user in the "Add Users to Debug Logs" page and click the Save button.  But when I am returned to the Debug Logs page, the user I just selected does not appear!  To make matters worse, this only occurs with a few users - namely the users I need for my development and testing.  I am able to add my own user and several others - just not the ones that I need.

I have never seen this problem before so that led me to think it might be related to the Winter 14 release.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

CORRECTION - confirmed as bug - please see https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/16524/3382 for workaround instructions.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16387/user-is-not-getting-added-to-monitored-users-in-debug-logs : possible duplicate

Comment: Hi Bart, welcome to the site! This question was flagged as a duplicate, so I've closed it and re-routed — on StackExchange we try to keep things concise!

Comment: Since this was marked as a duplicate, would you please post the workaround as an answer to the other question?