# Monitored Users automatically removed from Debug Logs

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, debugging

As everyone probably knows,

When I use Debug logs to monitor codes and processes,

I have to specify a “Monitored Users”,

Which is in this case myself,

But after just a few tests I am removed for some reason automatically from “Monitored Users”,

And I have to add myself again and again,

This is very frustrating,

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can stop it?

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16387/user-is-not-getting-added-to-monitored-users-in-debug-logs

Comment: looks duplicate of above question

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate - it seems to be asking why the user gets removed after a number of tests rather than not saved.

Comment: Bob Buzzard is correct, this is not the same as the other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add yourself as a monitored user, that will record logs for the next 20 transactions - see the "Log Requests Available" in the image below.

[image]

As you execute transactions this number reduces until it hits zero, at which time the platform stops monitoring your transactions.  You can hit the reset link to reset the count to 20, but it will still be consumed.

If you are monitoring your own transactions (i.e. you are the currently logged in user), you may find using the Developer Console improves things, as this doesn't require you to set yourself up as a monitored user (though I have needed to occasionally - no idea why) and it continues to monitor transactions until you close it (it can time out, in which case you get a "resume checking logs" button to start monitoring again.

Comment: Sometimes if you reset and do not navigate away from the page it stops decreasing

Comment: This usually means that you reset, which accesses the URL with an additional reset parameter, then you go into a log file, then you hit the back button which reloads the page with the additional reset parameter and puts the count back to 20.  That's how I used to use it before the developer console came along to help a bit.